# Displaying (or filtering) features in one layer based on features selected in another

Tags: qgis, isochrone

I have points in a layer "Site-Centroids".

I generate a lot of isochrones (polygons) around them, into "Isochrone_Site-Centroids".

With all the isochrones displayed, the map is too busy.

What I want is that no isochrones are initially displayed.

Only when the points from the original "Site-Centroids" are selected, do I want the corresponding isochrones become visible.

The fid's from the "Site-Centroids" are carried over to the isochrones in "ftid", so in the isochrone / polygon layer, I was hoping to use:

```
is_selected(get_feature('Site-Centroids','fid',ftid))
```

either as a rule in the rule-based symbology, or as filter on the entire feature.  In both cases, nothing is ever displayed.

So, is what I'm trying to do possible (show/hide features in one layer based on selections in another) and, if so, is my approach flawed or just buggy?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your *Isochrone_Site-Centroids* layer have a field named "ftid".
Assuming that your *Site-Centroids* layer have a field named "fid".
(If I am not understanding your use, please comment and I will edit this answer.)

Assuming also, that there are a single feature in *Site-Centroids* layer for each *fid* value.

---

You can control the rendering of the geometries of the *Isochrone_Site-Centroids* layer, whose *ftid* attribute matches the *fid* attribute of the feature selected in the *Site-Centroids* layer.

Use the *Rule-based symbology* of the *Isochrone_Site-Centroids* layer with the following expression:

```
is_selected( 'Site-Centroids', get_feature( 'Site-Centroids', 'fid', "ftid"))
```

It is necessary to indicate, to the `is_selected()` function, the layer on which the selection will be checked. If not, I observed that it assumes an unexpected behavior.

**UPDATE** (thanks for the observation!):

Also, it is necessary to add a dependency from the isochrone layer to the crentroid layer.

Comment: Thank you! it was also necessary to add a dependancy from the isochrone layer to the centroid layer.  Your edited version using rules is - I think - simpler than the generated geometries aproach, but I learnt a LOT by looking at that strategy.  I'd never noticed them before.

Comment: You are welcome! I thought it was wrong to send an empty string to the geometry generator (I was generating an invalid geometry for features that did not follow the rule), and I decided it was better to change my answer instead of updating it. The same I am seeing that it is not necessary to evaluate the truth condition, allow me to edit my answer once more. By the way, I'm not adding a dependency between the layers, and the expression works well. But I was testing with proof layers (with three and four features each) and have not referential integrity issues.

Comment: Yes, it's necessary to add the dependency. I had not realized because I had the isochron layer in edit mode. It was nothing related to integrity, I edit the answer once again.