# Selecting through one-to-many relationship

Tags: qgis, relates

I'm trying to make a species distribution project where I can select a species from a non-spatial list of species and the selection would highlight (select) all the counties to which the species has been attributed.

Simplified example data:
species, a non-spatial table of species (CSV with header):
"species"
"Mus borealis"
"Mus australis"

species_distributions, a non-spatial relation table (csv with header):
"species","county"
"Mus borealis","North"
"Mus borealis","Central"
"Mus australis","South"
"Mus australis","Central"

counties, a spatial feature class representing county boundaries (first row = field name):
"county"
"North"
"South"
"Central"
"West"

So if I select "Mus borealis" from the species table, the "North" and "Central" counties would be highlighted in the map. Seems like a simple scenario, but I have been unable to uncover a solution on my own. The closest I've found is a plugin "Select by relationship" but it doesn't appear to be available for QGIS 3 (I'm using QGIS 3.4.3). I have a PostGIS server available.

Answer (score 5):

**First option is:**

First open `Plugins | Settings` and enable `Show also experimental plugins`

[image]

Now you can install `Select by relationship` plugin

[image]

Now set up two relations in `Project --> Properties --> Relations`

First is:

- Name: sc (or whatever)
- Referenced Layer: species_distributions
- Referenced Field: county
- Referencing Layer: speciescounty
- Referencing Field: county
- Id: sc (or whatever)
- Strength: Association

Second is:

- Name: sd (or whatever)
- Referenced Layer: species
- Referenced Field: species
- Referencing Layer: species_distributions
- Referencing Field: species
- Id: sd (or whatever)
- Strength: Association

[image]

Now activate the plugin and the relations.

[image]

When you now open the attribute table of `species` layer and select your species, the countys will be highlighted.

[image]

[image]

[image]

For my example I used exactly your species, counties and stuff. The one in the middle is "Central" and so on...

**Second option is:**

Use only `species_distibutions` table and `county` file. And select the species inside `species_distributions`. Add a rule based renderer to `county` file with the following rule `is_selected( 'species_distributions', get_feature( 'species_distributions', 'county', "county"))` and a second one with `ELSE`. When you now select the `species/counties` in `species_distributions` the `counties` will get a different style. This option was inspired by another great question/answer yesterday here: [QGIS3: displaying (or filtering) features in one layer based on features selected in another](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309197/qgis3-displaying-or-filtering-features-in-one-layer-based-on-features-selecte). I bet there must be some way to also include `species` table and make your selection in there, but so far I could not make it work.. will update if I find a way.

Comment: First option works like a charm. You wouldn't believe how long I've been fiddling with this. I'll try the second option once I get over the euphoria.